# Чувствительной к регистру в Access

Tags: sql, access, office

Подскажите, как можно сделать, что бы Access был чувствителен к регистру в условиях where?

По умолчанию, как я понял, Access пофиг на регистр.

В интернете я находил костыль с использованием InStr.

Неужели нет другого способа?

Answer (score 2):

Можно указать тип сортировки в запросе при помощи ключевого слова `COLLATE`, но нужно учитывать кодировку.

[Пример](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5747698/how-to-make-sql-case-sensitive) можете посмотреть на англоязычной версии сайта.

Comment: Я попробовал и не работает или я что-то делаю не так... На сколько я понял в том вопросе, который вы мне привели идет речь о том, что из Access коннектятся к MS SQL, а там это работает...

Comment: Вы бы показали что пробовали. Тогда можно было бы точно сказать не работает или действительно что-то сделано не так. А, вообще, насколько точно сам вопрос описывает проблему, настолько точно ей соответствует и ответ. Без обид. Если говорить о работе конкретно с "родными" БД Access, то Microsoft рекомендует работать с 16ричными кодами символов. Ссылка на пример в следующем комментарии (здесь не уместилась из-за ограничений длинны).

Comment: [Пример](https://support.office.com/ru-ru/article/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D1%81-%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0-8fea1de4-6189-40e7-9359-00cd7d7845c0?ui=ru-RU&rs=ru-RU&ad=RU) можно найти на официальном сайте поддержки Office.